# Azure DevOps private agent - how to install node using nvm

Tags: ubuntu, azure-devops, nvm

I am trying to setup a private build agent for Azure DevOps on Ubuntu. And I need to use npm task for builds.

I tried to use nvm to install the latest node, and the installation was successful:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash
nvm install 11.10.1
```

I can check `node -v` and `npm -v`. But when the npm task is executed from the pipeline - it fails with

> Unable to locate executable file: 'npm'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

In my PATH I have `/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin` and `ls -l` shows:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 500 500 38 Feb 28 06:00 /usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js

I also added 777 (just to try it!) for npm-cli.js, and still no luck.

I also found this similar question - https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1862

How to properly install node and npm using nvm on Ubuntu agent for Azure DevOps?

Comment: did you restart the agent after installing npm?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes

Comment: AS a separate note - agents do not automatically marked as having npm capability either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporarily solution I installed node with

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

instead of nvm and it is working fine.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT ok, accepted. I have not done it before because I was waiting for a better solution from some guru here :)

Answer (score 4):

To get this to work I ended up creating a bash script that proxies to nvm, and then tells the agent to update the PATH variable to the current NVM.

Create a file at `/usr/local/bin/nvm` containing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Store the current path so we can check to see if it changes
OLD_PATH=$PATH

# Normal NVM stuff
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

# Execute NVM and pass all the arguments
nvm $@

# Check to see if the path has changed, and if an azure agent is running the
# command by checking the existence of the $AGENT_VERSION variable.
if [[ "$OLD_PATH" != "$PATH" && ! -z ${AGENT_VERSION+x} ]]; then
    # Grab the current node executable Something like:
    #  /Users/digitaldev/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin
    CURRENT_NODE=$(nvm which current)
    # Resolve to directory of the node executable Something like
    # /Users/digitaldev/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3
    BIN_DIR=$(dirname "$CURRENT_NODE")
    # Tell Azure Pipeline to update the PATH [1]
    echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$BIN_DIR"
fi
```

Make the file executable:

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/nvm`

Now when an Azure Pipeline runs `nvm` it'll update the path to look for the nvm version of node.

[[1] Logging Commands PrependPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#prependpath-prepend-a-path-to-the--path-environment-variable)

Answer (score 3):

## Just the nvm

I create a template like this based on the instructions from [nvm.sh](https://nvm.sh) and set the NVM_DIR and PATH accordingly.

```yaml
steps:
  - bash: |
      curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
      export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
      [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
      nvm install
      nvm use
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NVM_DIR;]$NVM_DIR"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]$PATH"
    displayName: "Install Node.js"
```

I also add a `.nvmrc` as documented in [nvm.sh](https://nvm.sh) so that the version of node to use is specified.

Then I use it in my pipeline as follows

```yaml
steps:
  - template: templates/install-node-js.yml
  - bash: |
      node --version
```

## With caching and node dependencies

This is my template for installing node and also doing caches to the packages in `package-lock.json`.

```yaml
steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'nvm | "$(Agent.OS)" | .nvmrc'
      path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nvm
    displayName: "Cache NVM"
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
      path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/node_modules
    displayName: "Cache node dependencies"
  - bash: |
      set -e
      if [ $(System.Debug) ]
      then
        set -x
      fi
      if [ ! -s $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh ]
      then
        mkdir -p $NVM_DIR
        curl -so- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
      fi
      . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh || true
      nvm install
      nvm use
      npm ci
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]$PATH"
    env:
      NVM_DIR: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.nvm
    displayName: Install Node and dependencies
```

Comment: I'll add the caching portion once I get it working.  That's why I exposed the NVM_DIR variable.

Answer (score 2):

Azure DevOps has included `nvm` on their Linux and macOS build agents for a while now.

If you want to utilize the work they've done to create your own agent, this repo has all the code they use.

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/

The Ubuntu Linux agents are using Packer (https://packer.io) to provision the VMs.

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/tree/main/images/linux

We use the Azure hosted agents and something like this to setup a Node project (or React Native/Cordova/Ionic mobile build), the most important part is any time you want to use `nvm` or a package installed by it (project or global scope) you need to `. ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh`.

```yaml
    steps:
     - script: |
        # Setup node using nvm
        # NODE_VERSION=12         # or whatever your preferred version is
        # We are using .nvmrc instead of specific version
        npm config delete prefix  # avoid a warning
        . ${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh       # This is the most important bit to utilize nvm
        nvm install # uses .nvmrc implicitly
        nvm use
        nvm alias default $(cat .nvmrc) 
        # nvm alias can understand eg. lts/erbium better than 
        # nvm_version_path which can't resolve the lts/* codenames
        VERSION_PATH="$(nvm_version_path $(cat $(nvm_alias_path)/$(cat $(nvm_alias_path)/default)))"
        which nvm
        # This will inject the node version we told nvm was default to the $PATH
        echo "##vso[task.prependPath]$VERSION_PATH"
        # Optionally upgrade npm here or using `nvm install-latest-npm`
        #npm install -g npm # upgrades to latest that supports lockfileVersion@2
        npm install
```